# How to sort an array of objects based on object priority value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have function as follows:

```
export const updatePriorities = (data, draggedItem, targetItem) => {
  const draggedItemPriority = draggedItem?.priority;
  const targetItemPriority = targetItem?.priority;

  if (draggedItemPriority === undefined || targetItemPriority === undefined || draggedItemPriority === null || targetItemPriority === null) {
    return data;
  }

  const minPriority = Math.min(draggedItemPriority, targetItemPriority);
  const maxPriority = Math.max(draggedItemPriority, targetItemPriority);

  const newData = map(data, (item) => {
    if (item.priority === draggedItemPriority) {
      return { ...item, priority: targetItemPriority };
    } else if (item.priority >= minPriority && item.priority < maxPriority) {
      const priorityOffset = targetItemPriority < draggedItemPriority ? 1 : -1;
      return { ...item, priority: item.priority + priorityOffset };
    } else if (item.priority === targetItemPriority) {
      return { ...item, priority: draggedItemPriority };
    }
    return item;
  });

  return orderBy(newData, 'priority');
};
```

My data is as follows:

```
const mockedData = [
  { name: 'Item 0', priority: 0 },
  { name: 'Item 1', priority: 1 },
  { name: 'Item 2', priority: 2 },
  { name: 'Item 3', priority: 3 },
  { name: 'Item 4', priority: 4 },
  { name: 'Item 5', priority: 5 }
];

const mockedDraggedItem1 = mockedData[1];
const mockedTargetItem1 = mockedData[3];
```

But `updatePriorities(mockedData, mockedDraggedItem1, mockedTargetItem1)` gives me:

```
[
    {name: "Item 0", priority: 0}
    {name: "Item 2", priority: 1}
    {name: "Item 3", priority: 1}
    {name: "Item 1", priority: 3}
    {name: "Item 4", priority: 4}
    {name: "Item 5", priority: 5}
]
```

instead of

```
[
    {name: "Item 0", priority: 0}
    {name: "Item 2", priority: 1}
    {name: "Item 3", priority: 2}
    {name: "Item 1", priority: 3}
    {name: "Item 4", priority: 4}
    {name: "Item 5", priority: 5}
]
```

The priority of the `mockedTargetItem1` is not updated correctly.

If the priority of `draggedItem` is higher then priority of `targetItem` then it works fine, but if priority of `targetItem` is higher than priority of `draggedItem` then it does not works as it should.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **(working)**

```js
// (item.priority <= maxPriority) instead of (item.priority < maxPriority)
if (item.priority >= minPriority && item.priority <= maxPriority) {
  const priorityOffset = targetItemPriority < draggedItemPriority ? 1 : -1;
  return { ...item, priority: item.priority + priorityOffset };
}
```

instead of **(bad)**

```js
if (item.priority >= minPriority && item.priority < maxPriority) {
  const priorityOffset = targetItemPriority < draggedItemPriority ? 1 : -1;
  return { ...item, priority: item.priority + priorityOffset };
}
```

therefore, don't need to

```js
else if (item.priority === targetItemPriority) {
  return { ...item, priority: draggedItemPriority };
}
```

```js
/**
 ** For Lodash Compatibility
 */
const { map, orderBy } = _

/**
 ** Function
 */
const updatePriorities = (data, draggedItem, targetItem) => {
  const draggedItemPriority = draggedItem?.priority;
  const targetItemPriority = targetItem?.priority;

  if (draggedItemPriority === undefined || targetItemPriority === undefined || draggedItemPriority === null || targetItemPriority === null) {
    return data;
  }

  const minPriority = Math.min(draggedItemPriority, targetItemPriority);
  const maxPriority = Math.max(draggedItemPriority, targetItemPriority);

  const newData = map(data, (item) => {
    if (item.priority === draggedItemPriority) {
      return { ...item, priority: targetItemPriority };
    } else if (item.priority >= minPriority && item.priority <= maxPriority) {
      const priorityOffset = targetItemPriority < draggedItemPriority ? 1 : -1;
      return { ...item, priority: item.priority + priorityOffset };
    } 
    return item;
  });

  return orderBy(newData, 'priority');
};

/**
 ** Data
 */
const mockedData = [
  { name: 'Item 0', priority: 0 },
  { name: 'Item 1', priority: 1 },
  { name: 'Item 2', priority: 2 },
  { name: 'Item 3', priority: 3 },
  { name: 'Item 4', priority: 4 },
  { name: 'Item 5', priority: 5 }
];
const mockedDraggedItem1 = mockedData[1];
const mockedTargetItem1 = mockedData[3];

/**
 ** Test
 */
console.log(updatePriorities(mockedData, mockedDraggedItem1, mockedTargetItem1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: You can chain i.e. `_.chain(data).map(item => ...).orderBy('priority').get()`

Comment: It seems to work. And what If I for example have two items with the same priority. For example: `const mockedData = [
  { name: 'Item 0', priority: 0 },
  { name: 'Item 1', priority: 0 },
  { name: 'Item 2', priority: 2 },
  { name: 'Item 3', priority: 3 },
  { name: 'Item 4', priority: 4 },
  { name: 'Item 5', priority: 5 }
];`

Comment: If the priority of the two items is the same, then the first if condition will evaluate to true for both items, but this does not affect the order. In this case, the second condition will not evaluate to true for any item.

Comment: Yes, but I'll end up with the result where two items have the same priority. It will not update the items and ensure that priorities are unique.

Comment: @rozsazoltan Can you please check this one also? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579293/how-to-properly-replace-value-of-an-object-in-an-array-and-sort-it-by-that-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579293/how-to-properly-replace-value-of-an-object-in-an-array-and-sort-it-by-that-value)

Answer (score 0):

consider using lodash sortBy for this use case and for all your arrays operations.